# What does this blktrace output mean?

Tags: linux, performance-monitoring

I run blktrace and get lines like the following:

```
  8,0    0        4     0.000016614   783  P   N [kjournald]
```

What does the `N` stand for? The field it's in is supposed to indicate read or write actions, as far as I can  tell, and the documentation does not mention `N` as a possible output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:3hnTH4bmOSYJ:ablktrace.googlecode.com/files/report.pdf+blktrace+%2B+%22read%22+%2B+%22write%22+%2B+%22block%22+%2B+%22barrier%22&hl=vi&gl=vn) document, `N` stand for `None`:

- R: Read
- W: Write
- B: Barrier
- S: Synchronous
- N: None